# 414 Request-URI too long - Marketo REST API Get Muliple Leads by List ID

Tags: rest, marketo

I am extracting lead data using the '[Get Multiple Leads by List Id](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-list-id/)' REST API with GET method. However there are more that 650 fields that are required to be fetched. If I pass a comma separated list of all the fields as the URL param and make a GET request, the api returns a 414 Request-URI Too Long error.

Is there a way to fetch all the fields (more that 650) from marketo using the REST API?
The api does not support POST method.

Error response in POSTMAN:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
    <center>
        <h1>414 Request-URI Too Large</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
        <center>nginx</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 650 fields or 650 rows ? handling such a large number of fields is already an headache, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using POST method and passing the fields parameter as a post parameter.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" 
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" -F "fields=company" 
"https://<endpoint>/rest/v1/list/1001/leads.json?_method=GET"
```

Comment: can you print an example of this?

Comment: `curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" -F "fields=company" "https://<endpoint>/rest/v1/list/1001/leads.json?_method=GET"`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know a solution for the REST API, however you can use the SOAP API because it will return all fields by default. Use getMultipleLeads: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/getmultipleleads/, specify leadSelector=StaticListSelector, staticListName = your list name or staticListId = your list ID.

Comment: Thanks @Jep for your suggestion. However the SOAP API is very slow and almost always times out for lists with large number of leads. Marketo had suggested us to use the REST API for this which would be faster than SOAP.